# Add search domain in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: network-manager, dhcp

It seems like network-manager doesn't support search-domains in the network-manager anymore when using DHCP. How to configure an additional search domain when using DHCP? Seems strange to me that the configuration has been removed.

Comment: Can i ask you what DHCP server using? Maybe your DHCP server does not configured correctly. Currently there is no way to figured it out what is the problem.
Show us something useful. Type `systemd-resolve --status'.

Comment: It is separate window-stuff that handles this search-domains so it doesn't happen automatically on linux. So I need to set them manually.

Answer (score 2):

Just run nm-connection-editor and complete the missing Information in the IPV4-Section.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? A more complete answer may help people in the future, too 

Comment: There seems to be bugs when adding search-domains to vpn-connection. Deletes the vpn-connection from Settings/Network and the tray.

Answer (score 0):

To get this to work with my wired connection, I did "sudo -E nm-connection-editor" to get the GUI.  Added the search domains, saved the result.  The additional domains did not appear in /etc/resolv.conf until after I rebooted.